# Is there a conventional name for a mathematical function that "steps" a number toward $0$?

Tags: terminology, convention

Consider the following two functions:

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x + 1\\
f(x) &= x - 1
\end{align*}

As these functions increment and decrement $x$, we could call them the $increment$ and $decrement$ functions. I'm not sure if that is the conventional mathematical name for them (nor am I concerned with that). My question is if there is a conventional name used for the following function:

$$\forall x \in \Bbb Z, \ f(x) = \begin{cases} x + 1, &x < 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ x - 1, & x > 0 \end{cases}$$

The only name I could guess at would be a $step$ function since it "steps" a number toward 0.

Comment: Let $x= -0.1$, then $f(x)=0.9$, so it steps away from 0.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Instead of $x+1$ and $x-1$, consider $\frac x2$ maybe. This reduces the absolute value of the parameter involved (and in short, you can write that function as $sgn(x)\left|\frac x2 \right|$). I don't know if these functions have a name, though.

Comment: Do people actually use "increment" and "decrement" for the functions $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto x-1$? When I read "increment" and "decrement" I think of operations that are performed in a computer program (or a denotation thereof), which are not at all the same things as the mathematical functions $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto x-1.$

Comment: I don't know what they're called, if anything, in the mathematical world. You are correct, though, that a programmer would usually name them `inc` and `dec` for "increment" and "decrement".

Comment: I doubt there is a special name for this function.  I would not call it a step function, because that's usually reserved for functions like $f(x) = 1$ for $ x\geq 0$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x< 0$.

Comment: @YujieZha I am only working with integers, so that case does not apply. I guess I should specify that in the question.

Comment: The first 2 functions are usually called successor and predecessor.  They only be increment and decrement under assignment.  The most similar named function I know is ${\rm sgn}$, you could write $f(x) = x + {\rm sgn}(x)$.  You could call it "increment by ${\rm sgn}$" or so.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's technically a step function according to Wikipedia's definition.  But that's a much larger class of functions that doesn't narrow it down.

Comment: I think your function is new and interesting. I don't have any applications for it now, but it is nice and symmetric with $f(-x) = -f(x)$ whereas the other two functions are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In signal processing, machine learning, and convex optimization, the function
$$
f_\lambda(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+\lambda & \text{if $x\le-\lambda$,} \\
0 & \text{if $x\in(-\lambda,\lambda)$,} \\
x-\lambda & \text{if $x\ge\lambda$}
\end{cases}
$$
is known as [*soft thresholding*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wthresh.html) or [*shrinkage*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~suvrit/teach/yaoliang_proximity.pdf) by $\lambda$.

Comment: Can you write a little something about why this has applications in convex optimization? It sounds pretty cool.

Comment: @goblin: I guess it would be more accurate to say it appears in applications of convex optimization (performed componentwise, it's the proximal operator of the $L^1$ norm), not specifically in the core theory of convex optimization itself.

Comment: To be concrete, it's a proximal operator because $f_\lambda(x)=\operatorname{argmin}_y \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^2 + \lambda |y|$